# How many NGinx redirects is too many?

Tags: performance, redirect, nginx

I'm working on a news centric website thats been around for years and is steadily accruing more and more page redirects.  Currently we have around 375 redirects and are adding about 5-10 a month.

I know that NGinx is very, very fast at handling redirects, but presumably there must be some number of redirects that will affect performance in a meaningful way, and I would feel better if I knew how many that would be.  Hundreds?  Thousands?  Millions?

We are able to handle large volumes of traffic by caching popular pages for a minute or two at a time in Memcached (reducing load on our database, the obvious bottleneck), but NGinx still has to route that traffic.

Is this something I should be at all concerned about?  How many redirects is too many for a high traffic website?

[edit: as suggested, I've also posted this at [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/191088/how-many-nginx-redirects-is-too-many)]

[edit: here is the answer I accepted at ServerFault]

> A redirect is not really a problem as
>   there's no backend being contacted.
>   Just Nginx. And Just Nginx is really,
>   really fast. As in 10,000+ connections
>   per second fast
>
> You should probably worry more about a
>   cluttered configuration file before
>   you worry about if Nginx can handle
>   it.

Comment: You may consider asking this on Server Fault as well.

Comment: Since you have accepted an answer to this question on Server Fault, maybe you should update this one so everyone knows?

Comment: After further testing, it looks like the upper limit for redirects for a high traffic website is somewhere in the thousands.

Answer (score 2):

"Redirect" means an HTTP haeder (301 or 302), so serving this header is even easier than static file serving for nginx. I've benchmarked, it can handle 9k request per second per cpu core.

Answer (score 0):

If you have *tons* of redirects, you may want to look into [OpenResty](http://openresty.org/) bundle for nginx as it allows you to interface nginx to MySQL, Drizzle, MariaDB.. While the performance might not be an issue even with thousands or tens of thousands of URLs stored in [redirect files](http://kcode.de/wordpress/2033-nginx-configuration-with-includes), the redirects are likely more convenient to manage when stored in a database.